# What is the part of speech of "over the past two quarters?"

Tags: parts-of-speech

What is the part of speech of "over the past two quarters" in the sentence below? Is it an adverb? If so what is it modifying?

> Yet the revenue and profitability figures of the three over the past two quarters are not terribly different

Comment: Doesn't it answer the question when? Phrases that answer the question when -- shoudn't that serve as an adverb?

Comment: The preposition phrase 'over the past two quarters'  arguably modifies the whole of 'the revenue and profitability figures of the three are not terribly different' and would usually not be seen as adjectival.

Comment: Thanks for adding your take! Even better, edit to add it to the original question; comments are more ephemeral. By the way, if you're asking because you're learning English, there's a separate [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) site where future questions might be a better fit.

Comment: Phrases don't have "parts of speech".